# Prove that the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is continuous at $x=-1$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Prove  that the function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is continuous at $x=-1$. You should give a proof that is directly based on the  definition of continuity.

I saw many similar questions on this website, but none of them gave me a satisfactory answer. I more or less understand how epsilon-delta proofs work but my problem lies more in the algebraic manipulations probably. So here's my "attempt".

Definition of continuity; for $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$

> $$\forall \varepsilon >0 \ \exists\delta>0\ \forall x \forall x_0 \in A:|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$$

So from what I understand, the procedure for epsilon-delta proofs are as follows:
1. Plug the point of interest $x_0$ into $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$
2. Write $x$ in terms of $\varepsilon$
3. Then plug $x$ into $|x-x_0|<\delta$
4. Find $\delta$ in terms of $\varepsilon$. Done

At step 1, we have $\left|\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{1}{2}\right|<\varepsilon$. Step 2 is where I'm stuck because of the 2nd degree polynomial in the denominator. First, I did this: $\left|\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}\right|<\left|\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{1}{2}\right|<\varepsilon$. Then, I wasn't too sure about what to do, I thought about getting rid of the "$1$", but that would screw up my inequality. I thought about factoring $x^2+1$, but it doesn't have any real roots. I tried inverting the fraction, but that led me to nowhere. And I've already exhausted the tools I have. **How do I proceed?**

Apparently, epsilon-delta proofs are the most basic building blocks of analysis. And I'm already failing, this is both embarrassing and depressing...

Comment: $x^2+1 \ge 1$ may be helpful.

Comment: Looks like you need to study the laws of inequality, with emphasis on the triangle inequality, because the inequality $\left|\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}\right|<\left|\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{1}{2}\right|$ is not true for all $x \in \mathbb R$. It's certainly false for $x=-1$, for example.

Comment: dont be depressed: the start of something generally is the hardest part

Comment: Epsilon-delta proofs are generally difficult for anyone who sees them the first time, nothing to be ashamed of. See [How to prove a limit exists using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/65667/272831), [Should a high school introductory calculus class teach $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/456960/272831), and [How do people pick $\delta$ so fast in $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1677604/272831).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: If $|x+1| <\delta $ where $0 <\delta <1$ then $x<-1+\delta$ and this  implies $x^{2} >(-1+\delta)^{2}$ .Hence $|\frac x {x^{2}+1}+\frac 1  2|=\frac {(x+1)^{2}} {2(x^{2}+1)}<\frac {\delta^{2}} {2(1+ (-1+\delta)^{2})}$. Can you proceed?

A further hint: If you choose $\delta $ to be $<\frac  1 2$ then $(-1+\delta)< -\frac  1 2$ which implies $(-1+\delta)^{2} >\frac 1 4$.

Comment: Thank you, let me think about this for a minute, I'll get you an answer.

Comment: Another hint maybe?

Comment: @Sckizel I have added one more hint.

Comment: I know I need to express $\delta$ in terms of $\varepsilon$, but I just don't see how. I give up. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Sckizel Take $\delta <\sqrt {\epsilon} \sqrt {1+\frac 1  4}$.

Comment: How did you come up with $\delta$?

Comment: Your desired inequality is $$(*) \quad \left|\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{1}{2}\right|<\varepsilon$$ The inequality that has been proved, assuming that $|x+1|<\delta$ for some unknown value $\delta$, is $$(**) \quad \left|\frac x {x^{2}+1}+\frac 1  2\right|<\frac {\delta^{2}} {2(1+ (-1+\delta)^{2})}$$ Now ask yourself the question: *What further inequality, in addition to $(**)$ implies $(*)$*?

Comment: To put this more abstractly: If you desire to prove $$(*) \quad a<c$$ and you know that this is true $$(**) \quad a<b$$ what further inequality, in addition to $(**)$, implies $(*)$?

Comment: @LeeMosher If $a<b$ and $b<c$, then that implies that $a<c$. Similarly, if $\left|\dfrac{\delta^2}{2(1+(-1+\delta)^2)}\right|<\epsilon$, then from $(**)$, I get $(*)$. Now, how do you justify $\left|\frac{\delta^2}{2(1+(-1+\delta)^2)}\right|<\epsilon$? Is it an arbitrary choice made to fit the problem?

Comment: Your goal is to *find a value of $\delta$*. By setting up that inequality and solving for $\delta$, *you've found it*.

Comment: Remember, to prove $\delta$ exists, you must *find* the appropriate value. For this problem, that comes down to solving that inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ is continuous at $f(-1)=-1/2$ is finite and euals both the right and the left limits: 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^+} f(x)=
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{-1+h}{1+(-1+h)^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^-} f(x)=
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{-1-h}{1+(-1-h)^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I need. The problem asks explicitly to use the epsilon-delta definition of continuity.